# What should I use as my connect URL when using FB AUTHENTICATION?

Tags: facebook

{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: The Facebook Connect cross-domain receiver URL (http://www.beta.neighborrow.com/callback) must have the application's Connect URL (http://www.beta.neighborrow.com/callback/) as a prefix.  You can configure the Connect URL in the http://www.facebook.com/developers/editapp.php?app_id=2233125716\">Application Settings Editor."
   }
}

What should I use as my connect URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If callback is the particular XDReceiver, then your Connect URL should probably be http://www.beta.neighborrow.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would start by removing the extraneous `.com` from your "cross-domain receiver URL":

```
http://www.beta.neighborrow.com.com/callback
                               ^
```

Comment: done-- whats my next step:) i need a token... assuming that comes from the OAUTH-- do i have to set that up separatel?